# Inequality for a function of two variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, inequality, partial-derivative

Suppose we have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that the second order partial mixed derivative, $f_{xy}(x,y) < 0$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.  I am told that $x_1 <x_2$ and $y_1 <y_2$ implies that $$f(x_1, y_1) + f(x_2, y_2) < f(x_1, y_2) + f(x_2, y_1)$$

This intuitively makes complete sense.  If we increase $x$ and increase $y$ by a small amount, we decrease $f$.  I can't show this rigorously.  My attempt is as follows, but it is nearly certainly wrong so you may ignore it if it's not useful:

Define $$\Delta_xf(y) = f(x_2, y) -f(x_1,y) \\ \Delta_y \Delta_xf = \Delta_xf(y_2) - \Delta_xf(y_1) = f(x_2,y_2) + f(x_1,y_1) - f(x_1,y_2) -f(x_2,y_1)$$  Is it true that there is some mean value theorem type result that states that there exist $\tilde x, \tilde y$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$ and $y_1$ and $y_2$ respectively such that $$\frac{\Delta_y \Delta_x f}{\Delta y \Delta x} = f_{xy}(\tilde x, \tilde y)$$

for $\Delta y = y_2 - y_1, \Delta x = x_2 - x_1$?  If this were true, we'd trivially be done.  I've tried to prove this using the 1 dimensional mean value theorem for single derivatives.  We know that for every $y \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists an $x(y) \in (x_1, x_2)$  such that $$\frac{\Delta_x f(y)}{\Delta x} = f_x(x(y),y) \implies \frac{\Delta_y \Delta_x f}{\Delta y \Delta x} = \frac{f_x(x(y_2), y_2) - f_x(x(y_1), y_1)}{\Delta y}$$

If $x(y_1)$ and $x(y_2)$ were necessarily the same, we could just apply the mean value theorem in the univariate sense in the second argument of $f_x$ but this is not the case surely.  Therefore I'm thinking that this doesn't hold and I probably need a different strategy in order to show my original result.  Any advice/help would be massively appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any condition on continuity/differentiability of $f$?

Comment: Suppose $f \in C^1$ (continuous first order partial derivatives) and its second order mixed derivative exists and is negative for every point in $\mathbb{R}^2$